# Specifying restricted permutations in adonis2 in Vegan-package

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, vegan, permute

Similar questions have been posed earlier, but I have failed to correctly understand how to apply this to my exmperimental design.

Experimental design:

- 9 blocks with an unbalanced number och plots in each block.
- 35 plots with 3 samples per year and plot.
- Each plot were randomly assigned a Treatment, with the condition that all treatments must be represented in each block.
- Blocks were divided into two groups A and B.
  Group A sampled 2017 and 2018. Group B sampled in 2018 and 2019. Treatment was applied inbetween the sampling occassions. *i.e.* Before treatment for group A was sampled in 2017, then the treatments were applied and then after treatment sampled in 2018.

I want to do a PERMANOVA to examine if the beetle communities differ before and after treatment as well as between treatments. Since it is abundance data on the beetle community I have choosen to use Bray-curtis.

I want to use the adonis or the adonis2 functions in the Vegan-package. (I am open to suggestions though, but this question regards these two functions).

As I understand it the adonis-function uses a sequential sums of squares(similar to an ANOVA type 1). However, I would like to do an marginal-effects test using adonis2 but I can not seem to understand how to stipulate how to restrict the permutations.

This is what I've got so far, it runs, and gives me resonable results, but I am unsure whether I have restricted the permutations correctly.

```
perm <- how(nperm = 999, blocks = env$Block,  plots = Plots(env$Plot), Within(type = "free"))

adonis2(
  m_com_total ~    env$Treatment * env$Impact + env$Year,
  method = "bray",
  permutations = perm,
  by = "margin"
)
```

I am also unsure if I should write the restriction as:

```
..., plots = Plots(strata = env$Plot), Within(type = "free"))
```

Instead of

```
..., plots = Plots(env$Plot), Within(type = "free"))
```

This yields slightly different results.

I would greatly appreciate any helpful tips and suggestions.
I have read the vignette for permutations in the permute package. Since I still have questions I apparently did not understand this particular part.

Oh yeah, if it helps I have been told to specify the restrictions/design-structure in adonis as follows:

```
adonis(
  m_com_total  ~  env$Treatment * env$Year + env$Impact ,
  strata = env$Block:env$Plot:env$Trap,
  method = "bray",
  perm = 999
)
```

***Edit 2023-02-23:***
I still have not managed to resolve my question. I have read the vignette for permute multiple times, but I'm still confused.

Instead I circumvent it by asking different questions to my data and doing other analysis.

If it were to trigger anyone to want to help, here is a dummy data which mirrors my experimental setup:

```
df <- data.frame(Block = as.factor(c("A","A","A",
                                 "A","A","A",
                                 "A","A","A",
                                 "A","A","A",
                                 "A","A","A",
                                 "A","A","A",
                                 "B","B","B",
                                 "B","B","B",
                                 "B","B","B",
                                 "B","B","B",
                                 "B","B","B",
                                 "B","B","B"
                                 )),
             Plot = as.factor(c("1","1","1",
                                "1","1","1",
                                "2","2","2",
                                "2","2","2",
                                "3","3","3",
                                "3","3","3",
                                "11","11","11",
                                "11","11","11",
                                "21","21","21",
                                "21","21","21",
                                "31","31","31",
                                "31","31","31"
                                )),
             Trap = as.factor(c("60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300",
                                "60","180","300"
                                )),
             Year = as.factor(c("2017","2017","2017",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2017","2017","2017",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2017","2017","2017",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2019","2019","2019",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2019","2019","2019",
                                "2018","2018","2018",
                                "2019","2019","2019"
                                )),
             Plot = as.factor(c("Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After",
                                "Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After",
                                "Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After",
                                "Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After",
                                "Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After",
                                "Before","Before","Before",
                                "After","After","After"
             )),
             Treatment = as.factor(c("NR", "NR", "NR",
                                     "NR", "NR", "NR",
                                     "UR", "UR", "UR",
                                     "UR", "UR", "UR",
                                     "CR", "CR", "CR",
                                     "CR", "CR", "CR",
                                     "NR", "NR", "NR",
                                     "NR", "NR", "NR",
                                     "UR", "UR", "UR",
                                     "UR", "UR", "UR",
                                     "CR", "CR", "CR",
                                     "CR", "CR", "CR"))
                                             ,
             species1 = as.numeric(c("1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "150", "250", "51",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "11", "21", "11",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "10", "20", "10")),
             species2 = as.numeric(c("100", "200", "100",
                                     "100", "200", "10000",
                                     "10000", "20000", "1000",
                                     "150", "250", "51",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1100", "210", "110",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "10000", "2", "1000",
                                     "1", "2", "1",
                                     "1", "2000", "1",
                                     "10", "20", "10")))
```

Thanks in advance :)